# "Please tell me who you are" problem (mac)

Tags: git, macos

In order i simply wrote on terminal

```
git config --global user.mail "[my mail]"
git config --global user.name "[my name]"
Hugos-MBP:ProjetOpenSource beelee_the_bee$ git commit -m "Salan"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'beelee_the_bee@Hugos-MBP.(none)')
```

---

(beelee_the_bee is my mac name)

when i wrote `git config -l` i have the following answer : 
user.mail=hugo.vast@gmail.com     and 
user.name=Huugoo147

So in fact my name and mail are in, but i already have the message and i cant commit :?

I read all questions around my subject and i didnt found any solutions
Please help me ^^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+tell+me+who+you+are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually `git config --global user.email` instead of `user.mail`.